# automated deployments using chef

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I am running my ruby on rails e-commerce application running on couple of ec2 instances in the production. I have not enabled auto scaling since we do Continuous Integration, we do deployment when ever required. I using chef for the all the reasons. I am trying to figure out how to use chef to deploy code to the multiple ec2 instances automcatically and manual intervention. I tried to deploy the code during the initial ec2 instance works fine. But my question is how do I do it in the auto scaling mode so that instance pull the latest code from either github or bit bucket and deployes itseld after bundle updating and all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fair enough. This is what i do and it works fine:

I have created an AMI with below settings:

1. install [chef client](https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/chef_11.6.0-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb)
2. Create `/etc/chef` directory
3. Copy `your_company-validator.pem` from chef workstation to AMI at
   `/etc/chef/validation.pem`
4. Create `/etc/chef/client.rb` as below.

If you use chef-solo, make the changes accordingly.

```
cat >> /etc/chef/client.rb <EF
log_level        :auto
log_location     STDOUT
chef_server_url  "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/your_company"
validation_client_name "you_company-validator"
EF
```

Now, you have all above stuff configured in the AMI for chef bootstrap.

When you launch the AMI (using autoscaling or any other way), provide `user-data` where in it will run the chef-client with run_list of your choice. I provide below user-data:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > /etc/chef/firstboot.json << EOL
{"run_list": ["recipe[java::oracle]"]}
EOL
chef-client -j /etc/chef/firstboot.json > /tmp/initialize_client.log 2>&1
```

basically, I am creating a .json file where I would specify the recipe/role/run_list I want to run. Once you provide the user-data, it will get executed on the 1st boot and chef-client will be run along with the run_list.

I think this is what you are  looking for.
so to summarize:

1. Create an AMI with pre-installed `chef-client, client.rb and
   validation.pem`
2. and then provide `user-data` at the time of instance launch.

This works perfectly for me. Let me know if this set-up gives you any trouble. I have been using this for quite some time.

So when I launch my instance using autscaling, it gets automatically chef-bootstrapped along with the recipes of my choice.

**ASSUMPTION**:
you have all your recipes/roles created on chef-server before doing  this. else the bootstrap will eventually fail.

Comment: Hello @slayedbylucifer sounds amazing!!! I will try it out soon and keep u updated

Comment: Hi I tried the process which you suggested but, after booting up ec2 instance it throws an error Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401).
Server Response:
----------------
Failed to authenticate as 'ip-10-128-94-138.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal'. Ensure that your node_name and client key are correct.
If these settings are correct, your client_key may be invalid.

How I am suppose to debug it and what would be problem.

Comment: when the chef-client runs for the 1st time, it would create client.pem itself. was there any client.pem in your image left from any prior run of chef-client? Also, Do you have your validation.pem key copied on the node ?

Comment: I don't understand why create AMIs with chef pre-installed... The "knife bootstrap" command will install chef and automatically configure the /etc/chef directory. Better still you could use the ec2 plugin from knife and additionally spin up the VM.

Comment: @Mark O'Connor, `knife bootstrap` or `knife ec2` plugin is no help when you are spinning up instances via AWS autoscalling.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I agree with the slayedbylucier because, chef doesnt cover or I can its not one stop solution for all the ec2 problems.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer Ahhh, now I understand what you're doing.