# How to launch amazon ec2 instance inside vpc using chef without using a gateway machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife, amazon-vpc

I am using chef to create amazon EC2 instances inside a VPC. I have alloted an elastic IP to new instance using `--associate-eip` option in knife ec2 server create. How do I bootstrap it without a gateway machine? It gets stuck at "Waiting for sshd" as it uses the private IP of newly created server to ssh into it, though it has an elastic IP allocated?
Am I missing anything? Here is the command I used.

```
bundle exec knife ec2 server create --subnet <subnet> --security-group-ids 
<security_group> --associate-eip <EIP>  --no-host-key-verify --ssh-key <keypair>
--ssh-user ubuntu --run-list "<role_list>" 
--image ami-59590830 --flavor m1.large --availability-zone us-east-1b  
--environment staging --ebs-size 10 --ebs-no-delete-on-term --template-file 
<bootstrap_file> --verbose
```

Is there any other work-around/patch to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got around the issue by using the `--server-connect-attribute` option, which is supposed to be used along with a `--ssh-gateway` attribute.

Add `--server-connect-attribute public_ip_address` to above knife ec2 create server command, which will make knife use public_ip_address of your server.

Note: This hack works using knife-ec2 (0.6.4). Refer `def ssh_connect_host` [here](https://github.com/opscode/knife-ec2/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/ec2_server_create.rb#L716g)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I have tried and faced 2 other issues (which have been solved). I just want to share my experience, hoping it would help other folks: **(1)** Security group might prevent you to SSH into the intance ([see this](http://serverfault.com/questions/473451/how-to-create-an-ec2-instance-with-knife)); **(2)** You might need to add `--no-host-key-verify` option ([see this](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2012-04/msg00290.html) and `knife ec2 server create --help`)

Answer (score 1):

Chef will always use the private IP while registering the EC2 nodes. You can get this working by having your chef server inside the VPC as well. Definitely not a best practice.

The other workaround is, let your chef server be out side of VPC. Instead of bootstrapping the instance using `knife ec2` command follow the instructions over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19223957/1251660).
This way you will bootstrap your node from the node itself and not from the Chef-server/workstation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you say that having the Chef Server inside the VPC is not a best practice?
To me, it seems like it's the best approach -- it speeds things up, keeps the whole infra inside a secure space and keeps internet traffic to a minimum, which reduces cost.

Comment: Your chef server should ideally be on as separate infrastructure as possible so that in the event a monumental failure you can provision everything from scratch somewhere else.